# Jquery Full calendar control with holidays in colour

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I use jquery `fullcalander` control. I want to colour holidays in month view.And after click holiday open message about the holidays.
I use event to send holidays to calander. but its not working
Can anyone help me

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar
         ({


             allEvent: {
                 titles: '.........',
                 start: '07/24/2012'
             },

             eventSources: [
             {
            url: '@Url.Action("LeaveCalandar")',
            type: 'Get',
           data{username:user},
           dataType:"JSON",
            success: function() {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'yellow',   
            textColor: 'black' 
        }

        // any other sources...

    ],
             eventClick: function (calEvent, allDay) {
                 // $('#eventTitle').text(calEvent.title);
                 // alert(calEvent.title);
                 eventName = calEvent.title;
                 ShowDialog(eventName);
                 ShowDialog(calEvent.titles);

             },
```

This is my Event calandar action method

```
public JsonResult EventCalendarData(string username)
        {
        List<CalendarEvents> events = new List<CalendarEvents>();
        List<LeaveTransaction> leaveQuery;
        var query = (from sh in db.StatHolidays
                     select sh).ToList();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
             leaveQuery = db.LeaveTransactions
                .Where(lt=>lt.Employee.UserName.Contains(username))
                            .Select(lt => lt).ToList();
        }
        else
             leaveQuery = db.LeaveTransactions
                            .Select(lt => lt).ToList();

        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            events.Add(new CalendarEvents
                {
                    id = item.ID.ToString(),
                    title = item.Description,
                    start = ToUnixTimespan(item.DateofStatHoliday),
                    className = "custom",
                    allDay = true,
                });

        }
        foreach (var item in leaveQuery)
        {
            events.Add(new CalendarEvents
            {
                id = item.Id.ToString(),
                title = item.LeaveType.Type,
                start = ToUnixTimespan(item.StartDate),
                end =ToUnixTimespan(item.EndDate),
                className = "custom",
                allDay = true,
            });

        }

        return Json(events, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post some sample code that you have tried.

Comment: I understand that you are trying to color holidays. But why are you using events to color days in the calendar? Do you want holidays to be displayed as events or do you want the entire day in the calendar to be colored differently in case of a holiday?

Comment: I want to colour entire day in holiday.is there any method has to get holidays?

Comment: can u help me even  i am looking for same thing if u have knowledge pls tell me